# Ubuntu 15.04/15.10 does not play any audio after 'amixer set Master toggle' two times

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I used the 'amixer set master toggle' command to mute my music on the home server during a phone call. Afterwards I tried to use the same command to un-mute the mixers: Dind't work.

I tried to restore all my alsamixer settings – No change.
I tried to completely reset the alsamixer states – No change.
I reinstalled alsa and pulseaudio – No change.
I updated from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 – No change.

Any ideas where to look at?

*Edit: Current mixer states: [image: alsamixer]*

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [due to the interference of pulse audio](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/878986)

If you have pulse audio installed, `amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle` should do the trick.

Comment: It could also be on the device itself, press F6 to list devices within alsamixer. While pulse was full volume, I occasionally find the underlying card muted.